# HTML5 Javascript - How to select the full path of folder selection

Tags: javascript, html, path, directory

I am looking to have an icon button on a page that when 'clicked' opens a Browser Window Dialog, with the option of selecting a local folder.  The path is then returned and displayed on the webpage.

This is a folder I will look at later, but for now I just want to display the local path.

This small piece of HTML will return a filename, but I just want to select a folder.

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="submit" src="folder.png" type="file"/>
</form>
```

If you then change the input field you can select all the files (returning total number) in the folder you select:

```
<input id="submit" src="folder.png" type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory />
```

But I don't want all the files :) I am just after the full path name of that folder.

Is there a way to just return the folder name and path?

Thanks for any help in advance.

**UPDATE**
I want to eventually search that folder for file types specified by the user and on user action.  So not something that is automatic (or dodgy). It's similar to creating user settings/config - specifying a root folder for something.

Comment: `input.files[0].webkitRelativePath` , also, file inputs don't have a _src_ attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That returns the name of the first file in the folder, not the path of the folder. In my case 'Koro/K313_1.jpg'

Comment: This isn't possible with JavaScript, the file system is hidden from scripting by design (although I think server-side JavaScript can access the file-system of the server, but I've not played with Node.js to try it out).

Comment: I did wonder, though thought I'd seen something similar with uploading to GoogleDrive. But maybe I was wrong. I can access files on the server, etc. using Node.js. I wanted to scan and list the files in the folder, not upload them.

Comment: you can list all the files without knowing the full path, just use the _files_ collection on the populated input.

Comment: But you don't get the full path